# Can't work out why my JavaScript if statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't work out why the CSS change from display: none to block doesn't work.

I get the error in my browser: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null".

This is the line that I am confused about:

```
if(running2 >= 100){
    document.getElementById('finishedAlert').style.display = 'block';
}
```

To me it makes sense and the browser error is triggered when the running2 variable is greater or equal to 100px. Thanks for any help.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    
    <style>
    body {font-family: arial;}
    #container {width:100%;}
    .content {width:900px;margin: 0 auto;}
    h1, h2, button {clear:both;}
    h1 {font-size:18px; color:#111;}
    h2 {font-size:16px; color:#777;}
    button {display:block; background-color: #ddd; border: none; padding: 10px 28px;margin-bottom:20px;font-size:14px;outline:none;outline:0;cursor: pointer;}
    div.dice{
        float:left;
        color: #fff;
        width:32px;
        background:#111;
        padding:10px;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align:center;
        margin:10px 10px 10px 0;
    }
    .track {
        width:105px;min-width:105px;height:5px;max-height: 5px; background-color: #777;
    }
    .man {
        height:30px; width:5px;max-height: 30px; background-color: #111;margin-top: 40px;margin-bottom: 3px; position: relative;
    }
    .finished {display:none;color:red;}
    </style>
    
    <script>
    
    var running2 =null;
    
    function rollDice(){
    
        var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
        var die2 = document.getElementById("die2");
        var status = document.getElementById("status");
        var status2 = document.getElementById("status2");
        var status3 = document.getElementById("status3");
    
        var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var diceTotal = d1 + d2;
    
        die1.innerHTML = d1;
        die2.innerHTML = d2;
    
        var running3 = (diceTotal + running2);
        running2 = running3;
    
        status.innerHTML = "You rolled "+diceTotal;
        if(d1 == d2){
            status.innerHTML += " DOUBLES! You get a free turn!!";
        }
    
        status2.innerHTML = "The man has run " + running3 + " pixels so far";
        status3.innerHTML = "The man has " + (100 - running3) + " pixels left to run";
    
        document.getElementById('moveMan').style.left = running2 + 'px';
    
        if(running2 >= 100){
            document.getElementById('finishedAlert').style.display = 'block';
        }
    
    }
    
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>You get 10 rolls. You have to get the man to the finish line before or on the tenth roll.<br>The finish line is 100px away.<br>Good luck.</h1>
            <div id="die1" class="dice">0</div>
            <div id="die2" class="dice">0</div>
            <button onclick="rollDice()">Roll Dice</button>
            <h1 id="status"></h2>
            <h2 id="status2"></h2>
            <h2 id="status3"></h2>
            <h2 class="finished" id="finshedAlert">Finished!</h2>
    
            <div class="man" id="moveMan">
                
            </div>
    
            <div class="track">
    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Check your code first before posting! `<h2 class="finished" id="finshedAlert">` had a different ID than `document.getElementById('finishedAlert')`. Probably a typo but this was never checked.

Comment: @VDWWD Thank you for your help. I did check the code thoroughly and didn't see my typo. Some people probably don't check their code before posting which is who you bundled me up with but I always do so I don't inconvenience anyone. Missed this typo after many scans. Sorry for the simple error but thanks for showing me where it is.

Comment: *Some people probably don't check their code* Perhaps they don't, but they should. Some people probably don't debug their code either, but they should do that as well. Some people probably don't consult the console to see run-time errors, or make an effort to figure out what they mean, but they should.

Answer (score 2):

It was just a typo, you have misspelled the id (`finshedAlert` instead of `finishedAlert`) on the `<h2>` element. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you Cristian I usually pick up on my spelling errors but missed this one for the life of me. Thanks again.

Comment: It happens to me all the time i know how it feels, you know it should work but it doesn't. The rollDice function is too complex, I would break it in smaller functions and call them inside the rollDice - just a thought.

Comment: Typos should simply be VTC as typo, perhaps pointing out the typo in a comment (as someone already did).